# Update multiple rows in same table in different row

Tags: php, mysql

I have to update multiple rows in same table in different row as below table in single query.

[image]

**Queries:**

```
update util SET util_value='$util_value_desc' where util_head ='wc_contact_us'

update util SET util_value='$util_value_email' where util_head ='wc_email'

update util SET util_value='$util_value_mobile' where util_head ='wc_mobile'

update util SET util_value='$util_value_map' where util_head ='wc_google_map'
```

also for select query to get data in textfield

```
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT util_value FROM util where util_head='wc_contact_us'");

                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);


                $util_value=$row['util_value'];
                $util_value_email=$row['util_value'];
                $util_value_map=$row['util_value'];
                $util_value_mobile=$row['util_value'];
```

Comment: This does not seem like it is possible in a single statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an update with a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE util
SET util_value = CASE util_head WHEN 'wc_contact_us' THEN ?
                                WHEN 'wc_email' THEN ?
                                WHEN 'wc_mobile' THEN ?
                                WHEN 'wc_google_map' THEN ? END
WHERE
    util_head IN ('wc_contact_us', 'wc_email', 'wc_mobile', 'wc_google_map');
```

To the four placeholders `?` you would bind the following four PHP variables:

```
$util_value_desc
$util_value_email
$util_value_mobile
$util_value_map
```

But this is a fairly verbose query, and you might want to stick with separate updates, maybe within a single transaction.

Comment: i want this also in select query to fetch the row in textfield, how do i do

Comment: You should ask a new question.